# How to format the "createdAt" column created by MongoDB using moment?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, momentjs

The line below is how I tried to format a date string from the `createdAt` column **created by MongoDB automatically**.

```
{moment("2020-06-03T20:49:55.572Z", moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_MS).format('YYYY-mm-dd')}
```

The outout is "2020-49-We" which is incorrect obviously.

I followed the `moment` [document](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/):
[image]

This is the most similar date format that I can find to my date string.

Could anyone teach me how to make it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected 'formatted' value of this date? please mention. And why you have included `moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_MS`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My format was incorrect. The `HH:mm:ss` can not be omitted. So the correct code should be:

```
{moment("2020-06-03T20:49:55.572Z", moment.HTML5_FMT.DATETIME_LOCAL_MS).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}
```

And the output is "2020-06-03 20:49:55"

Comment: If you don't want the time `HH:mm:ss` *can* actually be omitted. The incorrect part was that you were using `mm` instead of `MM`

Comment: Tip: `moment` should be able to *parse* that input format just fine without specifying it explicitly. `moment("2020-06-03T20:49:55.572Z").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` should work just fine

Comment: @thammada You are absolutely right! Thank you so much!